# Cocos2d: all objects have been stopped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Gameplay like pool or bowling

So, there are two types of objects: 
- main - moving by action (runAction - CCMoveTo)
- other objects - which moving only after contact with main object (haven't own action)

How to detect when all objects will be stopped after moving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craete counter, that will be increased every time you run new action. When you want to move node, do it not with CCMoveTo, but with CCSequence with CCMoveTo and CCCallFunc inside. CCCallFunc will be called after CCMoveTo is finished. In the method, that you will pass to CCCallFunc you can decrease counter. When it's value will be 0, all objects are stopped.

Comment: Thanks for you solution. But as i said, i run action only for one object and all other object begin movement after collisions with first object or with each other. How can i run CCSequence for all rebounds and collisions

Comment: and how do you move your other objects? i don't see any piece of code in your post.